# Difference between the words "quantify" and " assess" in the following sentence

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, synonyms

According to Thesaurus, the words "quantify" and "assess" are synonyms. Is there, however, a difference in meaning between the two words in for example a sentence such as:

> The [some effect] effect cannot be **assessed** by solely observing changes in X, since other effects may also influence changes in X.

OR

> The [some effect] effect cannot be **quantified** by solely observing changes in X, since other effects may also influence changes in X.

Comment: Thesaurus is not a dictionary. Please consult a good dictionary before asking a question like this.

Comment: To add onto what @TRomano said, the fundamental problem with thesauruses is that **true synonyms rarely, if ever, exist**. There will always be subtle differences between the meanings of words, even if they are listed as synonyms. That's why you need to consult a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's overlap, but the words are fundamentally different in meaning. "**Quantified**" implies a **numerical approach**, where you're simply trying to gauge one or more particular qualities.

"**Assessed**" implies a more **holistic approach**; you're trying to observe X as a whole, rather than zoom into particular aspects.

**EDIT**: Look at the example for "**quantify**" on Google:

> It's very hard to quantify the cost.

This example makes sense, because cost is a **quantity**. You can measure it directly and refer to it in terms of numbers. On the other hand, look at Google's sentence for "**assess**":

> The committee must assess the relative importance of the issues.

Here you see a **weighing of various qualities *and* quantities**. It's the bigger picture. Note that from the second example, you see that "**assess**" *can* have a similar meaning to "**quantify**" when referring to money:

> The damage was assessed at $5 billion.